# Event listener not being appended for all elements

Tags: javascript, event-listener, appendchild

I've appended multiple anchor tag elements to my document, but only the first anchor tag triggers the function that I have at the bottom of my Javascript document.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>To-Do App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="toDos"></div>
    <script src="js/todo-app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
let toDo = [{title: "groceries"},{title: "laundry"},{title: "cook dinner"},];
const filters = {searchText: ''}
const renderToDos = function (toDo, filters) {
  const filteredToDos = toDo.filter(function (todo) {
    return todo.title.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchText.toLowerCase());
  });
  filteredToDos.forEach(function (todo) {
    const toDoElement = document.createElement('p');
    toDoElement.setAttribute('class', 'paragraph');
    const toDoDelete = document.createElement('a');
    toDoDelete.setAttribute('href', '#');
    toDoDelete.textContent = "Delete Item";
    toDoElement.textContent = todo.title;
    document.querySelector('#toDos').appendChild(toDoElement);
    document.querySelector('#toDos').appendChild(toDoDelete);
  });
}
renderToDos(toDo, filters);
// The function I'm trying to trigger with the remaining anchor tags
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function () {console.log("item deleted");});
```

Comment: `querySelector` will only return the first element in the scope provided (i.e. `document`) that matches the query. Try using `querySelectorAll('a')`, then converting the resultant HTML Collection to an array with `Array.from()`. You can then loop over this array and add a listener to each element.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are adding Array.from(). Can you explain further? Also I'm getting an error when I try and use querySelectorAll

Comment: You might want to try [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355907/how-to-select-all-a-tag-and-register-onclick-event).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select all <a> tag and register onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355907/how-to-select-all-a-tag-and-register-onclick-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify a mistake in my comment, it is not necessary to use `Array.from()` to convert the result since `querySelectorAll` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) and not an HTML Collection.

NodeLists have a built-in `forEach` method so it would not need to be converted in this exmaple. However, if you wanted access to most other array methods, particularly looping methods like `map` and `filter`, you would have to do it.

I believe this syntax should work for your code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('item deleted'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found another StackOverflow question that tries to do the same thing as you. You might want to try this method:

[How to select all  tag and register onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355907/how-to-select-all-a-tag-and-register-onclick-event)